# Javascript Short-circuit expression gives confusing result

Tags: javascript, expression-evaluation

I am quite confused and don't understand what's going on with the output of this javascript expression evaluation.

```js
let m = 6;
let x=true;

m = m || x ? 10 : 0;
console.log(m); //10
```

In above example we have m = 6 || 10, so m should be 6 but it outputs 10.

```js
let m = 6;
let x=false;

m = m || x ? 10 : 0;
console.log(m); //10
```

Similarly in above expression we have m = 6 || 0 which should also output 6 but still it outputs 10.

Can someone please explain what's going on here?

Comment: ternary operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator?retiredLocale=de

Comment: `||` has higher [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than `... ? ... : ...`. Your statements are evaluated as `(m || x) ? 10 : 0`

Comment: the answer has less to do with ternary operator evaluation and more with operator precedence. I actually found the reason.
The expression 

    m || x ? 10 : 0;

was being computed as

    (m || x) ? 10 : 0;

and not as (which I wanted and was expecting)

    m || (x ? 10 : 0);

After adding brackets it is computing correctly.